# Diagram notation for events

Tags: diagram

I have a part of my program which can be called by various events. Each event however does something different before making use of this part. How can I represent these using a diagram? I was thinking of a flowchart but as far as I know a flow chart can have one start terminal, right?

Thanks a lot for the help,
Regards,
Krt_Malta

Answer (score 0):

UML Activity Diagram.

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/2802.html

You have a "wait for event" node that has multiple incoming events.  Each event has a different state transition.